# How do I make it so you cannot select the tabs at the top of the JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I was curious as to how I can 'disable' the tabs at the top so that you can select them, as I wish for my system to be only operated using button navigation. Any help much appreciated. Any questions, please ask! :)

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried and any insights as to where it's failing and the errors you're getting.

Comment: There is no code I've tried as I'm lost on where to start @Cohan. All I'm looking for is something that disables direct clicks on the tabs.

Comment: It does. You're a star. Thank you @Cohan!